# Android In-app rating promt submit button and stars are disabled on Production app

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console, google-play-core

I have integrated the Android In-app rating feature in my app. It was working fine during testing. But in production on some devices, submit button and stars are disabled.[image]
Can anyone know the actual issue with this?

Answer (score 3):

The `Submit` button should be disabled only in a version which was downloaded via Play Store’s app sharing feature.

See [Test using internal app sharing](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test#internal-app-sharing), it’s explicitly written there:

> Important: When using an app installed with internal app sharing, reviews can't be submitted. To emphasize this difference, the button is disabled in the UI.

So you need to make sure that you are working on a pure production non-app-sharing version.

Comment: This is the pure production app. I have downloaded this app via Google Play Store(not from the internal testing track or internal app sharing).Thank you

Comment: Got it.
I believe the next step should be turning off internal app sharing in Play Store and clearing Play Store data to rule out Play Store bug.

Comment: Not working, Still facing the same issue.

Comment: I can’t think of any other reason for this to happen.
Of course the initial state of the `Submit` button should be disabled until you actually fill the review (stars + review) but I’m sure you already tried that.

Sorry I can’t help you any further.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue got any solution for this??

Comment: What version are you using? Debug, Play Store ot Play Store with internal app share? (It's also been a while, need to verify that the instructions are the same)